# npx sequelize generate:migration --name=[name] keeps failing with Unknown argument: default

Tags: database, command-line, sequelize.js

I'm trying to generate a new migration with Sequelize, but following its help causes an error `Unknown argument: default`. I installed locally in my project and I am running the commands with `npx`.

```
gabriel@gabriel:~/Workspace/authtdd$ npx sequelize migration:generate --name=create_user

Sequelize CLI [Node: 12.4.0, CLI: 5.4.0, ORM: 5.8.7]

Options:
  --help             Show help                                                                                                                                                            [boolean]
  --version          Show version number                                                                                                                                                  [boolean]
  --env              The environment to run the command in                                                                                                        [string] [default: "development"]
  --config           The path to the config file                                                                                                                                           [string]
  --options-path     The path to a JSON file with additional options                                                                                                                       [string]
  --migrations-path  The path to the migrations folder                                                                                                             [string] [default: "migrations"]
  --seeders-path     The path to the seeders folder                                                                                                                   [string] [default: "seeders"]
  --models-path      The path to the models folder                                                                                                                     [string] [default: "models"]
  --url              The database connection string to use. Alternative to using --config files                                                                                            [string]
  --debug            When available show various debug information                                                                                                       [boolean] [default: false]
  --name             Defines the name of the migration                                                                                                                          [string] [required]
  --underscored      Use snake case for the timestamp's attribute names                                                                                                  [boolean] [default: false]

Unknown argument: default
```

But there is the option `--name` in the help list. Also, I tried a few different approaches: `--name:create_user`, `--name create_user`, but they say a "name" required. Same with yarn. Is it a bug?

Answer (score 0):

[link to sequelize manual.](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/migrations.html)

I guess you should also add the attributes. So your migration generation will look like the below

```
npx sequelize migration:generate --name=User --attributes=firstName:string,lastName:string,email:string
```